# How many kind of material resistance are there in engineering?

Tags: materials, material-science

I have seen many kind of material resistance mentioned scattering around, such as fracture resistance / deformation resistance / chemical resistance / weathering resistance and so on

But I cannot find the list of all of them together. I also wish there would be a table that list all material together with all resistance digitally format

Are there anywhere compile this information?

Answer (score 2):

Geick Technical Formulae has tables of common values, but that info is spread across several tables.

One you missed is electrical resistance. The book also contains tables for density etc